# Getting a range of tuples from an ordered SQLite table

Tags: sqlite

First I'd like to apologize if the topic seems vague; I always have a hard time framing them succinctly. That done, I'll get into it.

Suppose I have a database table that looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE The_table(
  item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,
  item TEXT);
```

Now, I have a pretty basic query that will get items from said table and order them:

```
SELECT *
FROM The_table
ORDER BY x;
```

where x could be either `item_id` or `item`. I can guarantee that both fields are order-able. My question is this:

Is there a way to modify the query I gave to get a range of the ordered elements: say from 20th element in the table to the 40th element in the table (after the table has been ordered) or something similar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it's called "between"

```
SELECT *
FROM The_Table
WHERE item_id BETWEEN 20 AND 40
```

This does exactly what it says - it looks for a value between the two numbers supplied. Very useful for finding ranges; works in reverse too (i.e. NOT BETWEEN). For more [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp).

If you want a specific row or group of rows (as your updated question suggests) after sorting you can use the `LIMIT` clause to select a range of entries

```
SELECT *
FROM The_Table
LIMIT 20, 20
```

Using `LIMIT` this way the first number is the starting point in the table and the second number is how many records to return from that point. This statement will return 20 rows starting at row 20 whatever that value is.

Comment: Looking at your answer further, it seems to me that it would get the items corresponding to values between 20 and 40, not necessarily the 20th to 40th items after the table is ordered.

Comment: Sorry that the question was worded ambiguously and thanks for the update.